# C# way of telling how many enemies alive

Tags: c#

I have my base game class and an enemy class.

When I instantiate an enemy using the base game I would like a integer to increase 
And when one dies I would need it to decrease the integer.

The end result being a new enemy spawns every few seconds so long as that integer is less than my MAX_ENEMIES

any way  I'm currently clue less and was hoping someone could direct me with how I should arrange this ( do I have the enemies increase the number when they spawn? )

Comment: You should look into a data structure to hold all your enemies. That way, you can count them from this data structure, and add/remove them.

Comment: @EricHotinger If only life were that easy.

Comment: Another option (besides @EricHotinger option) is to create a `static` property in your Enemy class.  Increment/decrement it as needed, and add a check to ensure it doesn't exceed `MAX_ENEMIES`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the basic idea: use a Factory Method. You may want to handle some of the specifics differently.

```
void Main()
{
    var game = new Game();
    game.CreateEnemy("Blinky");
    Console.WriteLine(game.EnemyCount);
    game.CreateEnemy("Clyde");
    Console.WriteLine(game.EnemyCount);
    game.DestroyEnemy(game.Enemies[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(game.EnemyCount);
}

public class Game
{
    public List<Enemy> Enemies = new List<Enemy>();

    public void CreateEnemy(string name)
    {
        if (EnemyCount >= MAX_ENEMIES) return;
        var enemy = new Enemy { Name = name};
        Enemies.Add(enemy);
    }

    public void DestroyEnemy(Enemy enemy)
    {
        Enemies.Remove(enemy);
    }

    public int EnemyCount
    {
        get { return Enemies.Count(); }
    }
}

public class Enemy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe add a link to a description of the design pattern as well,  OP may not be familiar with it.

Comment: Factory method design pattern: http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern. TLDR: It's a method whose responsibility it to create objects for you. In your case you want to encapsulate some business logic, so instead of spraying that all over your code, you put it in the only places that matter, the factory method CreateEnemy and its sibling DestroyEnemy.